# How to skip Maven plugin parent pom execution?

Tags: maven, maven-3, wildfly, maven-plugin, wildfly-8

I have a parent aggregator POM with multiple modules.  I have a `build/pluginManagement` in the parent since plugin execution is the same for each sub module.

If I execute in each sub module (`mvn package`) it works fine. If I execute in the parent: `mvn package -Pmytest`, I want to skip plugin execution in the parent module, so I added:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

However, it's not working.

Parent pom.xml:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xyz.jboss.config</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-config</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jboss-config</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>mytest</id>
            <modules>
                <module>jboss-system-properties</module>
                <module>jboss-security</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process-package</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/processed/scripts</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/scripts</directory>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process-clean</id>
                            <phase>clean</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/processed/scripts</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/scripts</directory>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-${project.artifactId}</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute-commands</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <execute-commands>
                                    <scripts>
                                        <script>${basedir}/processed/scripts/add-${project.artifactId}.cli</script>
                                    </scripts>
                                </execute-commands>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>remove-${project.artifactId}</id>
                            <phase>clean</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute-commands</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <execute-commands>
                                    <scripts>
                                        <script>${basedir}/processed/scripts/remove-${project.artifactId}.cli</script>
                                    </scripts>
                                </execute-commands>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Child pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xyz.jboss.config</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>jboss-system-properties</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <name>jboss-system-properties</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
</project>
```

I'm getting a file not found error.  The file is not supposed to exists here. The issue is why it's not skipping parent module execution.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] jboss-config ....................................... FAILURE [ 20.238 s]
[INFO] jboss-system-properties ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] jboss-security ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:
    execute-commands (add-jboss-config) on project jboss-config: 
    Execution add-jboss-config of goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:execute-commands failed: 
    Failed to process file 'H:\projects\xyz\jboss\trunk\jboss-configuration\processed\scripts\add-jboss-config.cli': 
    H:\projects\xyz\jboss\trunk\jboss-configuration\processed\scripts\add-jboss-config.cli 
    (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue.  If the execution id is parameterized, in my case:

```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>add-${project.artifactId}</id>
...
...
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>remove-${project.artifactId}</id>
...
...
```

to skip plugin execution, you'd have to explicitly specify the execution id and phase:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-jboss-config</id>
                    <phase/>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>remove-jboss-config</id>
                    <phase/>
                </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Now, it skips the parent, executes in all the children modules, and I only have one place for plugin configuration.

Note: I tried using static execution ids, but it has the side effect of skipping execution in the children modules as well.  Also, I'm not sure if all of these issues are just in wildfly-maven-plugin.